# disk usage full 100% but there is 112M available

Tags: server, disk-usage, disk

I already delete the large record backup but my disk is still full.

this image directory is `/datadrive/backups/project_name#`

[image]

when I run df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        29G   29G  112M 100% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           796M  1.6M  794M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3      117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/14784
/dev/loop1       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/certbot/2836
/dev/loop0       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/certbot/2772
/dev/loop2      117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/14447
/dev/loop4       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1828
/dev/loop5       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1822
/dev/loop7       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/23991
/dev/loop6       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop9       50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17950
/dev/loop8       50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/18357
/dev/sdb15      105M  5.2M  100M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sda        126G   20G  100G  17% /datadrive
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/802fd292812dc8a67070e25e35e2451f316a752e865f0039ffb364f1638625bc/merged
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/108460932da2686d4a2a499695f94b37b3b469835fb46b164ea120b82680320d/merged
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/63b31955563563b252aaab1927449e8e098aed31d7a70b311f259323087a2578/merged
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/65f5779b1b41de2fd4409f2e8597b50dd98ebc8eb6a6c78d4c691e6eeb3b37ae/merged
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3924361b7936348e88c15b5e988fec3d1ad474f2b19424a2c337930217778e26/merged
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2e19e3586c26f3d8a3ac45bf09b34a92ed31a483e5000e18c88efa94b2f2850/merged
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf8992e98fe2513c66de48e973c560cdd0bda14f9230f4620b63e3c84e4a3b4e/merged
overlay          29G   29G  112M 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6f620077876673d440610b79cd08ab30121f339232cfc466400ab79cf1bee7ea/merged
tmpfs           796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I don't know what's really going on here. I already reboot the server. but nothing happens.

here's my var/logs

```
total 135M
drwxrwxr-x  12 root      syslog           4.0K Mar 13 08:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 root      root             4.0K Feb  3  2022 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root                0 Mar  2 00:00 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              178 Mar  1 06:31 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              437 Jan 13 06:51 alternatives.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              438 Sep 21 06:37 alternatives.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              437 Sep 17 06:16 alternatives.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              164 Jun  3  2022 alternatives.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              409 Apr 22  2022 alternatives.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              134 Mar 16  2022 alternatives.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              595 Feb 11  2022 alternatives.log.8.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root      adm                 0 Feb 19  2022 apport.log
-rw-r-----   1 root      adm               350 Feb 18  2022 apport.log.1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      root             4.0K Mar  8 06:16 apt
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              9.9M Mar 13 09:05 auth.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               20M Mar  5 00:00 auth.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              1.6M Feb 26 00:00 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              1.6M Feb 19 00:00 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              1.6M Feb 12 00:00 auth.log.4.gz
drwxr-xr-x   3 root      root             4.0K Feb  2  2022 azure
-rw-rw----   1 root      utmp              22M Mar 13 09:05 btmp
-rw-rw----   1 root      utmp              64M Feb 28 23:59 btmp.1
drwxr-xr-x   2 _chrony   _chrony          4.0K Aug 25  2020 chrony
-rw-r-----   1 root      adm               17K Mar 13 08:24 cloud-init-output.log
-rw-r--r--   1 syslog    adm              768K Mar 13 08:24 cloud-init.log
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      root             4.0K Aug  4  2021 dist-upgrade
-rw-r--r--   1 root      adm               48K Mar 13 08:24 dmesg
-rw-r--r--   1 root      adm               49K Mar 13 07:44 dmesg.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root      adm               14K Jul 14  2022 dmesg.1.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      adm              1.9K May  7  2022 dmesg.2.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      adm               14K Mar  2  2022 dmesg.3.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      adm               14K Feb  2  2022 dmesg.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              29K Mar  8 06:16 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              40K Feb 28 06:37 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             4.0K May 28  2022 dpkg.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             4.2K Apr 29  2022 dpkg.log.11.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             3.2K Mar 29  2022 dpkg.log.12.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             2.8K Nov 30 06:40 dpkg.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             4.3K Oct 29 06:18 dpkg.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             3.8K Sep 28 06:08 dpkg.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             1.8K Aug 26  2022 dpkg.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             3.2K Jul 21  2022 dpkg.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root             4.4K Jun 29  2022 dpkg.log.9.gz
drwxr-sr-x+  3 root      systemd-journal  4.0K Feb  2  2022 journal
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              141K Mar 13 08:24 kern.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               49K Mar  3 06:01 kern.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              4.2K Feb 23 11:41 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              5.8K Feb 17 10:18 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               115 Feb  7 05:43 kern.log.4.gz
drwxr-xr-x   2 landscape landscape        4.0K Feb  2  2022 landscape
-rw-rw-r--   1 root      utmp             286K Mar 13 08:28 lastlog
drwx------   2 root      root              36K Mar  8 00:49 letsencrypt
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root                1 Mar 13 07:56 logfile
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      adm              4.0K Mar  8 00:00 nginx
drwx------   2 root      root             4.0K Feb  2  2022 private
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              1.1M Mar 13 09:05 syslog
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm             1016K Mar  8 00:00 syslog.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               87K Mar  7 00:00 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               84K Mar  6 00:00 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               88K Mar  5 00:00 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               93K Mar  4 00:00 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               84K Mar  3 00:00 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               87K Mar  2 00:00 syslog.7.gz
-rw-------   1 root      root             4.1K Mar 13 08:12 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log
-rw-------   1 root      root              13K Feb 28 23:43 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.1
-rw-------   1 root      root             1.5K Jan 31 20:00 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.2.gz
-rw-------   1 root      root             1.5K Dec 31 20:10 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.3.gz
-rw-------   1 root      root             1.4K Nov 30 19:38 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.4.gz
-rw-------   1 root      root             1.5K Oct 31 19:25 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.5.gz
-rw-------   1 root      root             1.4K Sep 30 21:29 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.6.gz
drwxr-x---   2 root      adm              4.0K Mar  1 00:00 unattended-upgrades
-rw-r--r--   1 root      root              12M Mar 13 08:54 waagent.log
-rw-rw-r--   1 root      utmp             111K Mar 13 08:28 wtmp
```

my `du -sh /*`

```
0   /bin
200M    /boot
20G /datadrive
0   /dev
5.9M    /etc
208K    /home
0   /lib
0   /lib32
0   /lib64
0   /libx32
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
16K /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/11307/task/11307/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/11307/task/11307/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/11307/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/11307/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   /proc
112K    /root
1.6M    /run
0   /sbin
2.4G    /snap
4.0K    /srv
0   /sys
60K /tmp
2.3G    /usr
32G /var
```

Comment: Please add the output of "sudo du -sh /*" to your question.

Comment: The root partition (`/` storage device) reserves 5% for the system. Generally when the disk shows as 100% full, only log files can be written to this location. You will want to try and get applications to use that `/datadrive` to read and write from if possible. If your `/var/log` file is large, then it will be important to see why so many logs are being written, as it's likely due to a configuration or hardware error 

Comment: @SorenA when i run that it feels like loading something???

Comment: @matigo i will post the var/log directory

Comment: the datadrive still 20G? why is that?? that folder is where i deleted the backup file in the picture